# Find duplicates in JSON array

Tags: json, jq

Does anyone know how to use jq to find the duplicate(s) in a JSON array?

For example:

Input:

```
[{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 4, "bar": 5}]
```

Output:

```
[{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}]
```

Answer (score 28):

One of many possible solutions in jq:

```
group_by(.) | map(select(length>1) | .[0])
```

Comment: Is there a way to use several keys in group_by filter in jq?

Comment: Yes, you can use any jq expression as the argument of group_by, e.g. `[ .key1, .key2 ]`.  But as noted elsewhere, `group_by` as currently implemented is inefficient for large arrays as it involves a sort.

Comment: Thanks again Peak!

Answer (score 3):

Solutions involving the built-in `group_by` involve a sort and  are therefore inefficient if the goal is simply to identify the duplicates.  Here is a sort-free solution that uses a generic and powerful `bagof` function defined here on a stream:

```
# Create a two-level dictionary giving [item, n] where n
# is the multiplicity of the item in the stream
def bagof(stream):
  reduce stream as $x ({};
    ($x | [type, tostring]) as $key
    | getpath($key) as $entry
    | if $entry then setpath($key; [$x, ($entry[1] + 1 )])
      else setpath($key; [$x, 1])
      end ) ;
```

```
# Emit a stream of duplicated items in the stream, s:
def duplicates(s): bagof(s) | .[][] | select(.[1]>1) | .[0];

# Input: an array
# Output: an array of items that are duplicated in the array
def duplicates: [duplicates(.[])];
```